# Understanding SqlAlchemy Sessions - How volatile are they?

Tags: python, session, sqlalchemy

I'm experimenting with SqlAlchemy, and trying to get a grasp of how I should treat connection objects.

So the `sessionmaker` returns a `sessionFactory` (confusingly *also* called `Session` in all their documentation), and you use that to create `session` objects that sound a lot like a database cursor to me.

What is a `session` object, specifically? Is it as ephemeral as a db cursor, or is it more material (does a session bind exclusively to one of the underlying connections in the engine's connection pool, for example)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Session object is not a database cursor; while using the Session you may open and close any number of individual cursors.  Within a single session's lifespan you may insert some records, run queries, issue updates, and delete.

There's a FAQ on the session where this [topic is addressed](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_9/orm/session.html#is-the-session-a-cache); in short, the Session is an in-memory object implementing an [identity map pattern](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_9/glossary.html#term-identity-map) which will sync the state of objects as they exist in your application with the database upon commit.

```
# User here is some SQLAlchemy model
user = session.query(User).filter(User.name == 'John').one()
user.name = 'John Smith'
```

At this stage, the database still thinks this user's name is John.  It will continue to until the session is flushed or committed. Note that under most configurations, any query you run from  a session automatically flushes the session so you don't need to worry about this.

Now let's inspect our `user` to better understand what the session is keeping track of:

```
> from sqlalchemy import orm
> orm.attributes.get_history(user, 'name')
History(added=['John Smith'], unchanged=(), deleted=['John'])
```

Watch once we've flushed the session:

```
> session.flush()
> orm.attributes.get_history(user, 'name')
History(added=(), unchanged=['John Smith'], deleted=())
```

However, if we do not commit the session but instead roll it back, our change will not stick:

```
> session.rollback()
> orm.attributes.get_history(user, 'name')
History(added=(), unchanged=['John'], deleted=())
```

The Session object is a public API for the underlying connection and transaction objects.  To understand how connections and transactions work in SQLAlchemy, take a look at the [core documentation's section on the topic](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_9/core/connections.html#sqlalchemy.engine.Connection.execution_options).

UPDATE: Session persistence

The Session stays open until explicitly closed via `Session.close()`.  Often transaction managers handle this for you automatically in a web application implementation, but, for instance, failure to close sessions you open in a test suite can cause problems due to many open transactions.

The Session holds your changes entirely in Python until it is flushed, either via `Session.flush()` or, if autoflush is on, when a query is run.  Once flushed the session will emit SQL within a transaction to the database.  Repeated flushes simply emit more SQL within that transaction.  Appropriate calls to `Session.begin` and `Session.begin_nested` will can create sub-transactions if your underlying engine/db supports it.

Calls to `Session.commit` and `Session.rollback` execute SQL within the currently active transaction.

Turn on `echo=True` when you initialize your engine and watch the SQL emitted by various Session methods to better understand what's happening.

Comment: Ok, so it sounds like a session object is a kind of esoteric caching proxy for a SQL database? This doesn't really answer the question of how ephemeral sessions are. Furthermore, the roll-back behaviour is intrinsic to the database (see sql `transaction`s), so the fact that you can roll-back doesn't meaningfully distinguish it from just plain SQL.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "ephemeral"?  It is quite clearly not a cursor.  Further, yes rollback is tied to the transaction itself, however its worth pointing out the session can be rolled back before any SQL has been emitted.  The session exists outside the SQL database, but does indeed mirror the behavior

Comment: `e·phem·er·al /əˈfem(ə)rəl/ adjective  lasting for a very short time.` E.g. how transient are they. Basically, I'm trying to understand how to translate operations that would have used a couple dozen cursors into something that uses SqlAlchemy. At the moment, I'm just persisting all the sessions for the entire application lifetime (one per thread).

Comment: FWIW, if the session can contain transactions that have not reached the database, that's pretty much the *definition* of a caching proxy. It's a ORM layer on top of a caching proxy on top of crappy documentation.

Comment: Yes, I am aware of what the definition of ephemeral is, but thank you for providing it just in case.  The answer was updated with more details about when the session closes.  I regret that, without more specific questions,I am at a loss as to what else to say on this.  IMO, it is a high quality implementation, and behaves reliably & providing sufficient transparency for you to dig around and understand what's going on.  I recommend turning `echo=True` on and playing with the Session in an interactive python session, such as IPython.  Let me know if you have any specific questions.

Comment: I'm marking your answer as accepted, though I wound up just dumping SqlAlchemy entirely, and going back to using `psycopg2` directly. I'm apparently doing stuff that's not within the very narrow use-case the documentation expects, and the docs are useless for anything outside of that use-case.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25956015/what-the-heck-do-i-get-when-i-subclass-declarative-base-using-sqlalchemy for more bizarre documentation difficulties. The whole behaviour of `declarative_base`, combined with the inability to just look up methods on a particular class in a coherent way (and there is no easy-to-browse class hierarchy in the docs anywhere!) made me just give up on sqlalchemy entirely.

Comment: `declarative_base` makes use of Python metaclasses, hence why it may seem a bit confusing. SQLAlchemy is really one of the most robust database management solutions written in Python, so I don't think your use case is outside its scope.  However, I understand the frustration of trying to work with someone else's abstraction layer.  I really believe it's a good tool, and you may benefit from spending a little more time on the side (perhaps outside your current application) learning the basics. Once you get them down, you'll notice everything begins to fall into place logically.  Good luck

Comment: Once I had it working, the SqlAlchemy stuff seemed quite robust. My issue is almost entirely with the poor documentation. I'm sure that the metaclass stuff done in `declarative_base` has an underlying logic, *but the documentation doesn't discuss it at all*. It basically says "here is how you use it (for one **extremely** narrow use-case)", and then moves on.

Comment: TL;DR the documentation is entirely not general. It's written with one use in mind, and does not discuss usage outside of that case at all.

Comment: `declarative_base` is just a convenient way to create tables; it's actually a newer feature of SQLAlchmey, and there are many examples in the documentation which do not use it at all.  If the ORM is not your style, there's extensive documentation around the `core` module on which the ORM is built.  I have seen more than a few folks who decided that is all they needed.  I wish I could be more helpful, but I have no idea what you're referring to/trying to do/confused about.  Sounds like you moved on and have a solution that's working for you.

Comment: `declarative_base` is a convenient way to get a **completely** undocumented object that somehow internally creates a table, and then you can use the few functions in examples to perform permutations on the table via the mysterious object it returns. If you want to do other things, you're stuck with a mysterious, [entirely undocumented object](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25956015/what-the-heck-do-i-get-when-i-subclass-declarative-base-using-sqlalchemy).

Comment: The approach `declarative_base` takes to making tables is *really* cool, and I was able to define the table schema I wanted with it without issue. The problems started when I wanted to do other things. For instance, I wanted to do a query that returns an item, check that I get only one item, and then if that was true, permute that returned item. Ok, so `session.query({decl_base_obj}).filter({stuff})`. Now, I want to check that I have one, and only one return. So call `one()`. But `one()` converts the row to a tuple you can't manipulate anymore. Wat? **Everything** was like that.

Comment: Like I said, you should look at the `core` documentation.  SQLAlchemy is a huge library, and yes, in the quick start on the ORM, they don't define the exact class of the return object. However, in the intro to the core, exactly that is explained: http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_9/core/tutorial.html#selecting  " The result returned is again a ResultProxy object, which acts much like a DBAPI cursor, including methods such as fetchone() and fetchall(). The easiest way to get rows from it is to just iterate:"

Comment: Re: `fetchone()`, I know that fetches one row. However, `one()` checks that there is one, and exactly one return row for the query. It's exactly the check I wanted, but it *does not* return a `ResultProxy` for some insane reason.

Comment: The documentation issues I was having are mostly related to what the hell you get back when you use `declarative_base`. You get an instance of `sqlalchemy.ext.declarative.api.Base`, which *doesn't exist* in the documentation.

Comment: The documentation for [sqlalchemy.orm.query.Query.one](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_9/orm/query.html?highlight=one#sqlalchemy.orm.query.Query.one) makes no mention of the fact that it doesn't return a ResultProxy. Actually, it doesn't describe what the hell it returns at all.

Comment: Ok, never mind. Apparently there are two, separate ways to query the database, only one of which returns `ResultProxy` objects. I was apparently using the wrong one.

Comment: I don't actually see *what* returns `ResultProxy` objects at all, short of calling `connection.execute()` directly. The only thing you get when searching the documentation for `ResultProxy` is the [`ResultProxy` class docs](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_9/search.html?q=ResultProxy&check_keywords=yes&area=default). Either their search is completely broken, or the methods that return `ResultProxy` do not mention this fact.