# What the heck do I get when I subclass `declarative_base` using SqlAlchemy?

Tags: python, sql, inheritance, sqlalchemy

I have a simple SqlAlchemy application:

```
import sqlalchemy as sa
import sqlalchemy.ext.declarative as dec
import sqlalchemy.engine.url as saurl
import sqlalchemy.orm as saorm
import sqlalchemy.schema as sch
import abc

class ItemTable():
    __tablename__ = 'book_items'

    @abc.abstractmethod
    def _source_key(self):
        pass

    rowid    = sa.Column(sa.Integer, sa.Sequence('book_page_id_seq'), primary_key=True)
    src      = sa.Column(sa.String,  nullable=False, index=True, default=_source_key)
    dlState  = sa.Column(sa.Integer, nullable=False, index=True, default=0)
    url      = sa.Column(sa.String,  nullable=False, unique=True, index=True)
    # [...snip...]

Base = dec.declarative_base(cls=ItemTable)

class TestItem(Base):
    _source_key = 'test'

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwds):
        # Set the default value of `src`. Somehow, despite the fact that `self.src` is being set
        # to a string, it still works.
        self.src = self._source_key

        print(self)
        print(type(self))
        print(super())
        print("IsInstance of ItemTable", isinstance(self, ItemTable))
        print("IsInstance of Table", isinstance(self, sch.Table))
        super().__init__(*args, **kwds)


def test():
    test = TestItem()


if __name__ == "__main__":

    test()
```

The idea is that the table schema is defined in `ItemTable`, and certain member attributes are defined as abstract. This ensures child-classes define certain member attributes, that are then used as value defaults by the instantiated child-class via some `__init__()` hijinks.

Anyways, this much works.

The issue I'm having is that I cannot for the life of me figure out what the hell the parents of `TestItem(Base)` are. I know it inherits from `ItemTable()`, but the intermediate inheritance of `dec.declarative_base(cls=ItemTable)` is inserting a whole bunch of methods and "stuff" into `TestItem(Base)`, and I don't know what is there, or where it's coming from.

I'm pretty sure there are some functions that would make my life a LOT easier with regard to modifying a row in the table, but since I don't know what `TestItem(Base)` is *actually* inheriting from, I have no idea where to look at all in the SqlAlchemy documentation.

The documentation *does* say about `declarative_base()`:

> The new base class will be given a metaclass that produces appropriate
>   `Table` objects and makes the appropriate `mapper()` calls based on the
>   information provided declaratively in the class and any subclasses of
>   the class.

Which makes me think that possibly `TestItem(Base)` is a child-class of `Table`, but `isinstance(self, sch.Table)` returns false, so either it's not, or the metaclass muckery is completely breaking `isinstance`.

Also, `TestItem(Base)` being a child-class of `Table` wouldn't make any sense logically, because you get instances of `TestItem(Base)` returned when you query, with each instance representing a *row*.

Anyways, I'm thoroughly confused.

---

## Update:

@Veedrac in the comments pointed out that `ClassName.mro()` gives you the full inheritance. In this case:
`TestItem.mro()` ->
`[<class '__main__.TestItem'>, <class 'sqlalchemy.ext.declarative.api.Base'>, <class '__main__.ItemTable'>, <class 'object'>]`

The fun thing here is that there are zero instances of `sqlalchemy.ext.declarative.api.Base` anywhere in the SqlAlchemy documentation.

The only thing documented along the `sqlalchemy.ext.declarative.api` path at all is `_declarative_constructor`, and there are ~2 unhelpful sentences there.

Comment: `ClassName.mro()` gives you the full, ordered inheritance hierarchy. Is that what you're looking for?

Comment: @Veedrac - Well..... That's *something*. It tells me: `mro [<class '__main__.TestItem'>, <class 'sqlalchemy.ext.declarative.api.Base'>, <class '__main__.ItemTable'>, <class 'object'>]`. The only fun bit here is that `sqlalchemy.ext.declarative.api.Base` doesn't **exist** in the SqlAlchemy documentation.

Comment: SqlAlchemy **desperately** needs some sort of autodoc facility. It doesn't even need to have anything other then just the method names and a inheritance graph, both of which can be done automatically.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, the end solution to my issues here was to just flat-out dump SqlAlchemy entirely.

I know exactly how to achieve what I want using SQL. I assumed that SqlAlchemy would make things easier, but it just lead to inheritance nightmares and lots of bizarre issues.

I'm sure there is *a* way to manage what I want in SqlAlchemy, but the documentation is so terrible that I'm unable to find it.

Comment: I used to hate sqlalchemy too coming from an active record style ORM (Django). But due to tech debts, I was forced to use it. After sometime it kinda clicks, and I get why the Identity map and Session do what they do. Its a pretty good solution IMO.  
Still, for 2 months me, *and my team*, did not want to use it at all, because of its insanely confusing and rambling docs.   
By god, the docs are a bullet to the head to someone trying to figure out how its philosophy works.  
In the end we managed to customise it and get it working, but I wished it wasn't so badly beginner unfriendly

Comment: Yeah, I'm kind of in the same boat. At this point (after using sqlalchemy for more then a year), I like *most* of it, and would use it over a bare SQL library without thinking much. OTOH, the onboarding experience is flaming crap.

Comment: On the suggestion of my friend, i'm planning to either help with the docs, or write an unofficial one for people who come from a Django/rails background. 
I don't get much time outside office, but I'll try my best. Would you like to help too?

Comment: I'm not exactly a great writer, but I'd be happy to help editing/etc...?

Comment: This post is 7 years old.  I hope things are better than back then.  I know I didn't share these experiences when I started and while I definitely ran into things, I can honestly say that ulike most ORMs and complex frameworks in general my love for SQLAlchemy has just grown.  It has some truly elegant solutions to complex problems and I really do far prefer the object notation query over things like JQL

Comment: @kunl Did you ever undertake that effort? I've long been thinking that SQLAlchemy could use a documentation rewrite done by a different author.

Comment: @MagnusLindOxlund Apologies for the late answer, but no, I didn't get around to it. 
I've also left the Flask/SQLAlchemy ecosystem a long time back, and I'm not sure if I'll get back to it anytime soon.